# To initialize 2D vector with zero values

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I want to construct an 2D-array of value passed `n`, basically I am trying construct n*n array and want to assign all values to zero. to do that `vector<vector<int> > ans(n, vector<int>(n));` I am trying like this but when check for the size it is returning value of `n` passed. where i am expecting the array size to be `n*n`

Is it right way to do like this? is there better way to do it.

```
   int n = 3;
   vector<vector<int> > ans(n, vector<int>(n));//initialize
   cout<<"size before :"<<ans.size()<<endl;
```

Comment: If you inspect the resulting object using your debugger's tools, what do you see?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i tried print vector i got 9 values with zero

  ```for(int i=0; i<ans.size(); i++) 
    {
       for(int j=0; j<ans[i].size(); j++)
       {
           cout<<ans[i][j]<<endl;
       }
    }```

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so my assumption of vector size n*n was wrong.. got it

Comment: What led you to believe it was wrong? You expected to get a 3x3 array. That's nine values. Your output shows nine values. What were you expecting to see, instead?

Comment: By definition, it's not an array as  it is not contigous. Well, on side, unless you don,t want to support raggedness or some kind of sparse matrix, you'd better not to nest a vector in vector.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik i was expecting array size to be 9 where it was resulting to 3

Comment: Why did you expect the size of `ans` to be 9, when the first parameter that gets passed to the constructor is 3, which sets the size of the vector?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik as i was nesting vector of vector i was thinking size of array would be n*n. anyways now i figured it out how this is working .. thanks

Comment: It's similar to array of pointers to arrays and got same problems/advantages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might like an idea to create own container class, which may or may not use std::vector as a storage. and would emulate 2D-array using vector or dynamically allocated  1D array. That way you would have a contiguous sequence of elements, you may treat the data as 1D array when required without taunting UB, etc. Such containers actually exist for this purpose in a number of libraries, e.g. `Matrix` class with `Dynamic` size in Eigen

Answer (score 2):

```
vector<vector<int> > ans(n, vector<int>(n));
```

It means you are specifying 'ans' as a vector of size 'n' where each element is a vector of ints. So when you use size(), it will return 'n' only because 'ans' has only 'n' elements. It won't return n * n.